# Regex for unicode characters not working in .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex, unicode

I'm trying to parse following string(It is french I guess):

L'OPéRATION NE PEUT êTRE EFFECTUéE

For this I've made this regex **[\p{L} ']+** which is working fine in regexbuddy(regex tester) even **[\w' ]+** is also working **but** problem is that same regex doesn't work when I run my .net code. It is only picking till **L'OP**.

Snapshots are attached.
Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] *as text* so we can reproduce the problem. Screenshots are a lot harder to work with than text.

Comment: You need to show how you instantiate the regex object. Are you sure that `é` after `L'OP` is a single Unicode code point? If there is a char with a diacritic, you need to use `[\p{L}\p{M} ']+`

Comment: It was never a problem of regex I just added this for reference that why a regex is not working in .net but working in regex tester.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the problem, it was all in a file and I was reading that file like

```
MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream(unzippedfile, false);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mm, true);
```

So, when string reached to regex object it was not same,
it became
L'OP�RATION NE PEUT �TRE EFFECTU�E.

However, I have changed my code now:

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mm,**Encoding.UTF7**, true);

And it all works fine. Thanks for your comments I got the clue from your comments.